# No recorre result set en (FOR o While) en Leaf 3.0

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, leaf

Estoy utilizando Leaf 3.0 (PHP) y por alguna razón que desconozco no recorre el result set de mi consulta. Mi objetivo es tomar información de algunos campos de la consulta.

Este es el código de Leaf:

```js
                db()->connect('127.0.0.1', 'bd', 'root', 'clave');              
                $resultadodevalidacion = db()->query("CALL SP_Consulta('$N1', '$C1')")->get();
                $result = collect($resultadodevalidacion); 
                db()->close();
```

Ahora, de ese "$result" hay unos datos (de los campos que trae) que los necesito para validar algunas cosas / reglas de mi API. Pero, por alguna razón cuando lo recorro e imprimo los datos para estar seguro que si los está tomando, no muestra nada.

Esto es mi código que pongo en Leaf, pero, que no me muestra nada y por lo tanto concluyo que no funciona:

```js
foreach($result as $ver) {
                                $Id=$ver['Id'];
                                $Act=$ver['Activo'];
                                $Idpermed=$ver['idp'];
                                $Nuser=$ver['no'];
                                $IdEsp=$ver['ides'];
                                $Espe=$ver['esp'];
                                $Idsuc=$ver['Ids']; 
                        }   
foreach($result as $ver) {
                                $Id=$ver[0];
                                $Act=$ver[1];
                                $Idpermed=$ver[2];
                                $Nuser=$ver[3];
                                $IdEsp=$ver[4];
                                $Espe=$ver[5];
                                $Idsuc=$ver[6]; 
                        } 
                        
response()->json($Id);         
return $Id;
```

Cuando ejecuto la API en el navegador navegador no muestra nada, ni siquiera 0, nulo, nada y cuando imprimo el resultado si muestra toda la información que viene de la BD. Cabe mencionar, que la conexión es de tipo PDO. No entiendo porque no me muestra nada. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: estás imprimiendo únicamente $ver[0]. Todo lo demás lo pisaste en el foreach

Comment: Mi objetivo, es tomar el valor del ID porque lo necesito para otras operaciones. Por eso:response()->json($Id);  return $Id; Es solo para probar que ahí está el valor que necesito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien. Debido a que el código nativo de PHP no funciona en este framework (Leaf) se tienen que usar estatus especiales para pasar los datos, pero, aún no entiendo porque no imprime los datos. En fin.

La respuesta es:

- Cuando se llama una consulta, se tiene que usar el termino: ->fetchAssoc();

```js
db()->connect('127.0.0.1', 'bd', 'root', 'clave');              
$resultadodevalidacion = db()->query("CALL SP_Consulta('$N1', '$C1')")->fetchAssoc();
$result = collect($resultadodevalidacion); 
db()->close();
```

Así asocia el resultado y se puede sacar un valor del arreglo:

```js
 $Idx=$resultadodevalidacion['Id'];
```

Entonces, puedo hacer uso de la variable. Espero, que alguien le sirva esta información.

Por favor, moderadores agreguen Leafphp al listado de etiquetas para no asociarlo con Laravel.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por compartir la respuesta. No soy moderador, pero agregué la etiqueta como se menciona en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags. Saludos